# How can I change the ruler behavior in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm working on a Word document that was given to me as a .doc, and I converted it to a .docx (I'm not sure if that's relevant but I'm mentioning it just in case).

I'm trying to fix various formatting issues it has, and one of the issues I've noticed is that at a certain point in the document, the indentation changes as a result of the actual ruler at the top of the document changing.

1. Why is this happening?
2. What can I do to "fix" it? (That is to say: have a consistent ruler / indentation throughout the document.)

[image]

Comment: If you are talking about the TAB stops it's always on Mouse click by default,, this you wanna to change?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: The margins changed at that point in the document.

I hadn't realized that the margins could vary throughout the document.  I pressed Ctrl+A to select the entire document, set a margin, and the problem went away.

Update: It seems likely (but I'm not sure) that the margin change coincided with a "continuous section break"--which I wasn't aware was a thing--that had somehow gotten into the document, possibly during the conversion to a .docx file. About 30 minutes after I changed the margins I realized that the document had many continuous section breaks littered apparently-randomly throughout it.